# Are questions about how to make anime and manga off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I spotted this question — [What software is used for making anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4/) — and would love to answer it, but I'm not convinced it's gelling with the other questions asked so far. Moreover, I know there's a [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) that may be more appropriate for these types of questions. So are questions about how to make anime and manga off-topic?

Answer (score 9):

I believe they should be off-topic. They're, as you said, better suited to [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) and are more about the animation process (not unique to anime) rather than the medium itself.

Comment: I agree. Unless the question deals with the cultural part of making Manga/Anime. If it's purely about how to draw/design something, it should go to [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: There are a lot of aspects that involve making a manga that don't involve graphic design, aren't there?  Like how to plan a story?

Comment: @LeeHai Then that would be on-topic on [Writers.se]. These are ***not unique to the anime medium*** and thus would fit better elsewhere.

Comment: @chirale It seems you feel very strongly. I suggest you make a competing answer.

Comment: Or Audio/Video Production.

Comment: see my comment on http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4/244 . This has **no** place to be asked on avp, nor on japanese, nor on graphic design. ***It would generate speculation***. They are no experts in ***japanese*** internals. Western internals are *not interesting in anime production*. Many consider western inferior. (Personally I so very seldom read western comics or watch cartoons, but love anime - it's for a reason: Japanese are generally *much* more advanced with it.) Japanese.SE won't do anime production, avp and graphics design are not japanese-specific. The only on-spot answer is here.

Answer (score 8):

As per my comment on [What software is used for making anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4/) and on OP:

- The question should be about *real knowledge* of *Japanese* production ***internals***.
- The question must have *nothing* to do with "may Adobe After Effects be good for" kind of speculation. ***Speculation is bad.*** *Speculation* **is** what *makes* these questions *'off-topic'*.
- The question should not be about software.
- The question must be *focused tightly* on the **knowledge** of how Japanese **actually** make anime, **not** on how they might.
- The question has no place on [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/), nor on [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/), and definitely not on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). Western artists and craftspeople don't work in Japan, and most of them probably have *no clue* how Japanese **actually** make anime. They are no experts in *Japanese* internals, and western internals *are not interesting in anime production.*
- There is a real question hidden there about Japanese commons of anime production that could be very special and quite distinct from anything else. Personally, I very seldom read or watch western-style, but love manga and anime. It's for a reason: Japanese are so much more *advanced* in them. Just like their seiyuu are of *much, much higher quality* and thus the seiyuu training *internals* would be equally interesting as the anime production *internals*.

Strictly throw away *all* speculation about *any* method or tool. Throw away *all* western stuff. Focus on actual *Japanese* production.

And then it is *on-topic*, and ***only*** on topic **here**.

---

**Edit:**

Questions like [How are visual novels written? [closed]](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/420/) *would* be very interesting *and* on-topic ***if*** they would ask how ***Japanese***  **actually** create manga, anime and visual novels.

The ***problem*** is that *instead* they ask how these things ***could be*** created. But that is *not* interesting and is off-topic, because it results in speculation and advice that *doesn't* explain how actual Japanese *achieve* their generally *very high quality*. It is true that any *general western software, graphic design or AV expert could give speculative ideas about how "some kind of animation"* **could** *be made*. They would make actual facts about western methods, *but most of them could only give* **speculations** about *Japanese* methods on *other* SE sites.

**But** if these questions are *re-worded* to *focus* ***only*** *on* ***actual Japanese*** *production method* ***knowledge***, then it makes them a very interesting and on-topic question.

Comment: I think this is consistent with what we are actually doing, just not documented very well. Questions saying "I want to make anime/manga, tell me how" are closed as off-topic, but questions asking "How is this particular step in creating anime/manga done?" are allowed. We have [tag:anime-production] and [tag:manga-production] for such questions, though unfortunately those tags have become somewhat broader and now include questions about the production of a particular series as well.

Comment: @LoganM thank you for pointing that out! I would love to read about *actual jap.* production. I'm still afraid that many like me may see two meaning in this questions title: after all, it's perfectly logical that you want to know about *actual* **japanese** production *because you want to learn what it takes to learn to achieve it yourself*. And at the same time, this same motivation makes you *completely disinterested* in speculation - however, the question's title doesn't decide on this, and actually incorporates both cases. This makes the title a little dangerously ambiguous in my opinion.

Comment: Regarding that particular question, it's one of the first ones from private beta (as is this meta question), and the rules were not established at that time. It's probably easier to re-ask the question in a more focused way than to try to get it reopened at this point. Also, while we do allow questions on anime production, specific production methods aren't something we have many experts in, so technical questions are likely to go unanswered here. They might get migrated to Graphic Design or some other SE site if they don't seem particularly anime-specific.

Comment: @naxa We're having a chat session this Saturday (25th May) at 1800 UTC. We are going to talk about some other stuff first, but we should have enough time to debate this matter afterwards. We'd be happy to have you there.

Comment: @LoganM yes I agree; but *anime-specific* production, I believe, has still the biggest chance *here*. It would make this site greater too! (I think it could make use of boost in users.) But I agree that there are few experts now. I have a hypothesis: *if* the site would *advocate* using *kana* for specific questions (boot with Qs on right jap. terms, maybe?) then it could *attract* actual *Japanese* people (I'm sure they are also interested and to lesser degree but also use stackexchange.) (Eg. japanese.stackexchange.com seems to be doing very well.) Then we would got experts eventually.

Comment: Adding a personal FYI to my prev., I'm surprised that there are not more kana here. I expect a lot of kana on an anime site. (See, well, any other anime site! ;) )

Comment: @JNat thank you very much I keep it in mind! Can't make promise -I got so much at workplace + exams in uni- but will see what can I do!

Comment: Like JNat here said, we have a chat cast soon, jump in and raise it there. Other than that, if you feel that the question should be reopened, edit it to improve its on-topicness then vote to reopen or flag it. Make sure to make it clear in a comment or the flag message why it should be reopened. Also, we're almost always active in chat, jump in and discuss it with us as well. Good luck and happy browsing :).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly disagree to banish this kind of interesting and smart questions from Anime & Manga. At a question like that, the right answer is to back in topic by listing software used in a specific anime as an example. I'm thinking about Hoshi no Koe, the first self-producted anime by Makoto Shinkai: in the booklet, software he used back in early 2000 are listed: Photoshop 5 (2D), Lightwave 6.5 (CGI), Commotion DV3, Adobe After Effects 4.0. Is this information irrelevant? Are question about techniques a taboo?

*Note: this was previously a comment, moved here after Aarthi suggestion above.*

Comment: Questions about techniques are not off topic. However, if you start getting into to much detail regarding, let's say Adobe After Effects 4.0, it will get very technical and would be better suited for [GraphicDesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). At least IMO

Comment: Agree, in-depth talk about a specific tool are off-topic. It's about seeing the difference about "hey, I want to make an anime, what software I can use?" (off-topic) and "What software Makoto Shinkai used in his first self-made movie?" (ok), as I replied in [this meta question](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/167/98) about creation processes.

Comment: @JNat See my comment on http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4/244 and on OP. This should be about *real knowledge* of *Japanese* production ***internals***. This must *nothing* to do with "may AE be good for" and that kind of speculation. ***Speculation is bad.*** *Speculation* **is** what *makes* these *'off-topic'*. The question must be *focused tightly* on the **knowledge** of how Japanese **actually** make anime. (**Not** on how they might.). And then it is *on-topic*, and *only* on topic **here**.

Comment: @naxa Yes, you make some very good points. I agree with your point of view.