# Is this question asking for anime script writing competitions On or Off Topic?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

The question in question is [**this one**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/6021/49). It asks for a list (although not explicitly) of anime script writing competitions in Japan, and falls under [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production).

The question is **currently [on-hold] as off-topic**, with this reason:

> "Questions on **making your own anime or manga** are off-topic as they involve specific expertise outside the scope of this community. See: [Are Questions about “How to make Anime and Manga” off-topic?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6/49)"

However, the question is not quite about making your own anime or manga, but rather about what script writing competitions exist. The reason for questions about making anime/manga being off-topic is that they "involve specific expertise outside the scope of this community". Thus, a question asking for a list of competitions does not fall under this category, since a more knowledgeable/informed member of the community is likely to be able to answer this, with relatively little research.

Still, the question may be considered off-topic for another reason: it asks for an out-of-universe list. These are *generally* considered off-topic, as per [our latest discussion on that matter](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/587/49). Note, however, that this was considered the general action course on this type of question, and the post states that "exceptions will be made depending on how well-defined the scope of the question is".

So how should we handle this question?
**Should it be left closed as is? or should it be closed for another reason (being an out-of-universe question)?

Or should it be reopened? If so, is the scope well defined enough, or should the question be edited?**

Comment: I don't think it's a question about how to make anime, but a question about competitions to create anime. Much like asking what film award competitions are being offered in a country. The OP should probably better define the time frame and scope of this question (e.g. What major prize competitions in anime are/have been offered annually? In Japan? In other countries?). There is a set number of these (along with ones in different categories) that happened in Japan each year, so if we focus on the major ones, the list shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: @Krazer I have the same opinion. Let's see what other people have to say about this.

Answer (score 5):

I am in agreement with Krazer on this one. I would say this question **should be reopened, provided it can be scoped better.**

First, this is the close reason given:

> Questions on making your own anime or manga are off-topic as they involve specific expertise outside the scope of this community.

This question does not *necessarily* involve making your own anime or manga. I never intend to be a movie producer, but I still find myself curious about movie awards, film festivals, and indie script writing now and then. The two are related only tangentially, if at all.

**However**, this question *does* mention that the OP's intent is to enter these competitions. (This was edited in after the initial close, though.) This should not be included in the question.

Second, I believe this differs from our typical list question issues. In fact, one of the most prominent reasons for disallowing them is the simple issue that [you generally need to know about a *huge* number of anime in order to answer them](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/588/274). That's not an issue here: There are only a finite (and not a large) number of anime script-writing competitions, and an answer really *need* only cover the major ones. It is possible that the OP wants to know about minor ones as well, but that at least needs to be clarified in the question.

Keep in mind that *major* carries a different definition for different people, but in this case I think it can generally be agreed upon. That said, here is how I would ask the question; it's brief, but I think it's to the point and still a reasonably acceptable question.

> **What are the more well-known anime script-writing competitions?**
>
> I'm familar with the [Animeka](http://animeka.jp/) anime script-writing competition, but it doesn't seem like there are many others out there. What major or well-known script-writing competitions exist for anime works?

Comment: I agree with the wording you propose for the question. +1