# Is this a forum for authors/creators?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask questions on how to start a collaboration in comics creation, is this forum appropriate for this question?

Comment: Take a moment and visit our tour page to get to know us better http://anime.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 4):

No.

This is a Q&A site dedicated to specific questions in regards to anime and manga.  Familiarize yourself with [what is and isn't on-topic here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> Not all questions have a home on Anime and Manga. Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here:
>
> - ... Questions on making your own anime or manga, as they involve specific expertise outside the scope of this community. See: [Are Questions about "How to make Anime and Manga" off-topic?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-questions-about-how-to-make-anime-and-manga-off-topic)