# Are questions regarding creating an anime magazine off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a question on this site regarding pages order for an anime magazine I am working on and surprisingly some people found it off-topic.

I'm really curious to know if it really is, because I always viewed StackExchange as an integrated site and that you will always find a community to ask any descent question you may have.
So if this community isn't the place for such a question, is there any other?

Comment: Related: [Are questions about how to make anime and manga off-topic?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6/2516)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stack Exchange is not as "integrated" as you may think (especially not this one). On the topic of your question, while tangentially about anime, is more so about content creation. Most of this community is unable to help with your question due to their lack of expertise in the matter. Unfortunately there is not really a venue that can assist you with this. We're Q&A site on a recreational topic, unlike some of our cooler, more professional cousins.

There is a lot that goes on and needs to be considered when creating and organizing content for a magazine, regardless of whether it's a professional or amateur endeavor. You need to consider things like target audience (and how appropriate the content is for who you target), cost of production, method of distribution, deadlines for content, illustrations and other media, not just how things should be ordered (typically magazine put things they know ppl want to see in the center, strategically placing color content can also help draw attention, how to manage it varies heavily on what and how you want to present your content).

That is why I made the suggestion to steer your question more so to resource collection of anime and manga periodical publication as a reference point to base your content creation effort. No topic is off-topic in our main chatroom, so I suggested you stop by for a bit of casual discussion.

Content creation is a very tricky subject to tackle like making your own anime or manga. There's a technical side as well as a creative side. We used to refer users to Design.SE, but such questions were not well received due to the very niche nature and perception of anime and manga with more "mainstream" crowds. So we try to redirect things to chat to at least try to help or point people in the right direction instead of saying look elsewhere. I can't speak for other communities, but we may not be able to offer much expert advice as professional, due to our lack of technical expertise, but we can at least try to some share our anecdotal experience and opinions are consumers of anime and manga subculture and media.

While what is offer might be meager in the grand scale of things, what's left of us will at least try to steer you in the right direction if we can help directly. What matters is context, you tell us what you need and we'll tell you where we might be able to give you a hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really made me understand how the system works.